# Can't create the db file (the db file on specific path) on the device (code attached)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to create a db file (SQLite) on the device disk - and all works fine with no exception - but the file does not created.

added these permissions

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The code:

```
public class DbHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myAppDatabase.db";                

private static final String PersistenceFolder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyApp" + File.separator;
private static final String  PersistenceFilePath = PersistenceFolder + DATABASE_NAME;


public DbHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, PersistenceFilePath, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    createTable1();
    createTable2();
}

private void createTable1(){
    // create table 1 with no exception
}

private void createTable2(){
    // create table 2 with no exception
}
}
```

Comment: How have you determined that the file is not created? You have a lot of unused code here related to external storage; your database is being created on internal storage.

Comment: I don't see the file in the folder that i define in the constructor.

Comment: Please explain **exactly** how you have determined that the file is not created. Are you using a desktop file manager? Are you using an on-device file manager? Are you using `adb shell`? Are you using something else?

Comment: To see the created db file you have to use a rooted device. If your device is not rooted, when you explore the destination path you can not see anything and the content of it is hidden from you.

Comment: I create the file on specific path - please read the code

Comment: Database will only be created when **`getReadableDatabase`** or **`getWriteableDatabase`** is called. Are you calling either? *When you use this class to obtain references to your database, the system performs the potentially long-running operations of creating and updating the database only when needed and not during app startup. All you need to do is call getWritableDatabase() or getReadableDatabase().* [Create a Database Using a SQL Helper](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok lets make this simple the code below decides if I have a SD Card if not we use internal storage but it gets the path then passes that PATH to DBHelper who creates the DB I will post the code to get the PATH first then the DBHelper code

```
    public void onAvail() {

    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) && (!state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY))) {

        File removable = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(this, null)[1];
        THE_PATH = String.valueOf(removable) + "/Documents/";

        //System.out.println("ALL TRUE ==> " + THE_PATH);

    } else {// if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)) {
        THE_PATH = "";
        //System.out.println("ALL FALSE ==> "+ THE_PATH);
    }
}
```

partial DBHelper code to create DB

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
public static final String DB_NAME = THE_PATH +"PassWord";
//public static final String DB_NAME = "PassWord";
// Code Above for Internal Storage ONLY
public static final Integer DB_VERSION = 1;
```